# Wrong Aspect Ratio for Contour Plot with Python (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, aspect-ratio, contourf

I import a fits file and basically want to plot it as a contourplot. The problem arises with the aspect ratio. The image has 320x240 dimensions and since I don't want the picture to be stretched, I want the ratio of the image to be 320/240 also.

Python, however, forces it to a square like thing, which is why I used `plt.axis('equal')`
This however creates white areas in the plotting area and I don't know how to get rid off them...

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!!

```
import numpy
import math
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scidatafile=fits.open('24-02-2015-PSF-OD00-iris15-30pin.fits')
scidata=scidatafile[0].data
oneframe=scidata[0]
oneframe[oneframe<0]=0
yvec=numpy.linspace(0,240,240)
xvec=numpy.linspace(0,320,320)
X,Y=numpy.meshgrid(xvec,yvec)
```

There it goes

```
plt.contourf(X,Y,oneframe)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.savefig('this.pdf')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should post a minimal working example. As you use data not made available, I just used some own dummy data.

Basically the problem is setting the aspect ratio before any data is in the axis. I don't know why and if it was me, I would mark this as bug not a feature. So instead set the aspect ratio after calling contourf.

I also don't understand why aspect=1 doesn't work for contourf, while it works for imshow.

```
    from numpy import *
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *

    # dummy data preparations

    x = linspace( -3.0, 3.0, 100 )
    y = linspace( -2.0, 2.0, 100 )

    def V( x, y=None ):
        if y == None:
            return 1.0/x
        xv,yv = meshgrid( x, y, sparse=False, indexing='xy' )
        return 1.0 / sqrt(xv**2+yv**2)

    rlev = sqrt(18.) / 2.**linspace( 0,4,10 )
    pic = V(x,y)

    # your try to plot it which results in white borders
    fig = figure()
    title('old version')
    contourf( x, y, pic, levels=V(rlev) )
    axis('equal')
    tight_layout()
    savefig('old.png')
```

Need 10 rep to post picture: 'old.png'

```
    # method without white borders
    fig = figure()
    title('new version')
    ax = subplot(1,1,1)
    contourf( x, y, pic, levels=V(rlev) )
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    tight_layout()
    savefig('new.png')
    show()
```

Need 10 rep to post picture: 'new.png'

Answer (score 0):

Using `pylab`, you can do it like this:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

yvec=np.linspace(0,240,240)
xvec=np.linspace(0,320,320)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(xvec,yvec)

Z = X**2 + Y**2 # function to plot

sx = 8
sy = sx*float(yvec.size)/float(xvec.size) # reset y-scale to match array dimensions

fig, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(sx, sy))
ax.contourf(X,Y,Z)
```

[image: Code output]

In plain matplotlib, I think you can get the same effect using `gcf()` to manipulate the figure.

Comment: I actually just figured that the problem seems to come from the colorbar. I didn't include in the source code (sorry my fault) cause I didn't think it had something to do with the problem.

So, when I add the colorbar
    plt.colorbar()
It scales the whole, i.e. plot and color bar to the ratio 320/240. This apparently squeezes the plot to something like 270/240 or whatever.